# Images are loaded in draft mode

Tags: graphics, document-classes, class-options, draft

I'm trying to load draft mode as an option for my class. Overfull lines are highlighted, but unfortunately images are loaded normally (not just as frame). Can someone please tell me why?

Class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}[template] 

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{iflang}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
    family=SBMT,%
    prefix=SBMT@%
}

% Declare class options         
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{draftmode}            
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*  

% if draft mode is enabled (true) pass option "draft" to class
\ifthenelse{\boolean{SBMT@draftmode}}{%
        \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{scrbook}
    }{}

\LoadClass[
    fontsize=12pt,              
    DIV=12,                           
    open=right,                 
    cleardoublepage=empty,      
    parskip=half-,                  
    headings=normal             
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack} 

% Basics
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
```

Document:

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}    
\documentclass[     
    draftmode=true ,        
]{thesis}
\setlength\headheight{30pt} 

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that in your custom class you load `scrbook` with `\LoadClass` and pass the options there, but you load `graphicx` using `\RequirePackage` in your own class. This causes the package loading to be outside the scope of `\LoadClass` and therefore the option is not passed.

You can check this when you uncomment `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` (and `\RequirePackage{pdfpages}` as well, because that package loads `graphicx` internally) and put `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your document, then the `draft` option is respected.

A workaround is to pass the option to `graphicx` explicitly (and to other required packages) using `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

Code:

```
% if draft mode is enabled (true) pass option "draft" to class
\ifthenelse{\boolean{SBMT@draftmode}}{%
        \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{scrbook}
        \PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
    }{}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already thought that the graphicx package is responsible for that issue. Are there other limitations of the draft mode if I do not change my code?

Comment: @joni the `pdfpages` package also has a `draft` setting (to print an empty box instead of the included pdf). Microtype has a `draft` setting that disables the functionality of the package. So also for these two packages that you require you need separate `\PassOptionsToPackage` statements. The other packages that you require don't have a draft setting as far as I know.